# How to display a sitmap horizontally?

Tags: plugins, css, sitemap

I've created a sitemap successfully using wp Realtime sitemap. I've read their instructions and made pages. but i want to show this sitemap horizontally which i attached .I created this sitemap using wp-realtime-sitemap plugin.Can anyone suggest me some plugins for doing sitemap horizontally?
[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? If I search for "css list horizontal" links like [this](https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_lists_menu), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15710701/horizontal-list-items) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49921602/how-to-create-a-horizontal-ul-list-in-css-grid) come up, showing various methods to do this

Comment: Welcome to WPSE, anondi.  You may need to edit your question so people can give you a relevant answer.  As @kero asked, what you have you tried so far? Include that in your question. Give a starting point based on something that shows you've made some original effort.

Comment: post a link to you page, I will send you CSS that will make it look horizontal

Comment: website hasn't been published over the internet ...I'm doing this task on local server(xamp/wamp)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This problem has been solved by writing custom css. Thank you all